# WebConfig URL Rewrites in IIS

Tags: asp.net, url, iis, url-rewrite-module

Have a ASP.NET solution and want to achieve 2 things: -

1. Redirect www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com
2. Have friendly URLs

So ... here is what I have added the system.webserver section of the webconfig...

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove WWW prefix" >
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://mydomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="homepage" stopProcessing="true" >
          <match url="^/wwwzone/homepage.aspx$"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/"/>
        </rule>
      <rule name="homepageReal" stopProcessing="true" >
        <match url="^/$"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/somepath/homepage.aspx"/>
      </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
          <add key="on" value="https"/>
          <add key="off" value="http"/>
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

This fails. The logic behind this is: -

- First rule takes care of redirecting www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com. This works. and with the rewriteMap it also handles HTTP/HTTPS correctly.
- The second rule is supposed to do a browser redirect if they request an unfriendly (real) URL.
- The last one is designed to convert the friendly URL back to the real URL, however this is a rewrite not a redirect.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns our was poor syntax in my regular expressions.

So, matching the real URL of the home page should have been

```
<match url="^$"/>
```

not

```
<match url="^/$"/>
```

And the subsequent rule to rewrite to the real URL should change in the same way.

So, for completeness, this one works...

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Remove WWW prefix" >
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
          <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mydomain\.com" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{MapProtocol:{HTTPS}}://mydomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="homepage" stopProcessing="true" >
          <match url="^wwwzone/homepage.aspx"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/"/>
        </rule>
      <rule name="homepageReal" stopProcessing="true" >
        <match url="^$"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/somepath/homepage.aspx"/>
      </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MapProtocol">
          <add key="on" value="https"/>
          <add key="off" value="http"/>
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```